# Problem with double slashes in Windows Path using Python

Tags: python, windows, docker, directory

I have an application that runs in docker and need to access a Windows directory to copy some files.
I created an environment varible with the path that is something like this:
PATH='\\drive2\dir1\dir2\dir3\@Health services'

But every time i try to execute this program I the directory is just not found. Trying to evaluate the expression I saw that PATH have become \\\\drive2\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\@Health services

I tried using r, single and double quotes, but nothing different happened.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Cant put an @ in your directory name maybe. to test if PATH takes, `cd $PATH` and see if it works, if it doesnt, PATH needs fixed.  so from your script try `posix.chdir(PATH)`

Comment: @ChristopherHoffman cd Path is bad idea, use `os.path.exists()` als better if use path as `path=r"\a\b\c"`

Comment: Yes thanks, also if windows try adding C:\\ to the beginning of your path, if linux /root/path/works/fine

Comment: @ChristopherHoffman The thing is that it's not in C. It's a folder inside the network. And '@Health services' is a valid directory

Comment: https://python-forum.io/Thread-trouble-with-os-listdir-on-a-network-drive suggests you have get the network drive labeled with a drive letter like `w:\\`

Comment: A generic environment variable should never replace the special `PATH` variable. Let's call it `SPAM` instead. Print out its value as `print(os.environ['SPAM'])`. There should be no single or double quotes in the printed value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe making it '@Health Services' at the end is proper windows format because the filenames with a space need single quotes (but nothing more should). You may also find a file's exact path by right clicking on it and then navigating through properties to General or Details.

Comment: Yeah, '@Health services' is a valid windows folder name. And the path i gave it the absolute path, it starts in \\drive2